# merge 2nd array in 1st array jquery?

Tags: jquery, arrays, merge, concatenation, unique

I have 2 arrays, `array1` and `array2`. Both have some values but not the same length.

I want to concatenate `array2` into `array1`.

I have tried this but it is not working:

```
array1 = array1.concat(array2);
```

Comment: did you try ? https://api.jquery.com/jquery.merge/

Comment: finally which array have values in this example?

Comment: *Merge the contents of two arrays together into the first array.* [jQuery.merge( first, second )](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.merge/)

Comment: What you have shown works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ch9n65wL/. If it's not working for you, please check the console for errors and edit the question if you have any.

Comment: Why in God's name is everyone recommending jQuery here? It's not needed. What OP already has works correctly...

Comment: I know jQuery is not required for this simple task but if the OP tags jQuery and not Javascript, expect some jQuery answers.

Answer (score 0):

To just merge the arrays **without** removing duplicates

**ES5 version use Array.concat:**

```
var array1 = ["foo","bar"];
var array2 = ["bar", "biz"];
var array3 = array1.concat(array2);
```

**ES6 version use destructuring**

```
const array1 = ["foo","bar"];
const array2 = ["bar", "biz"];
const array3 = [...array1, ...array2];
```

**Result**

```
// [ 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'biz' ]
```

**Merge the arrays WITH removing duplicates**

```
var array1 = ['foo', 'bar', 'biz'], array2 = ['delta', 'bar', 'foo', 'tango'];

var array3 = array1.concat(array2.filter(function (item) {

    return array1.indexOf(item) < 0;
}));
```

**Result:**

```
// ["foo", "bar", "biz", "delta", "tango"]
```

---

[more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items)